# Django - Showing the data in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've written a Django app for getting name, dob and image upload. The data seems successfully stored in the database. But when I try to retrieve it and show in the templates.. the corresponding page looks blank. One more thing, the image is stored in the sample folder and I don't know how to show it in the templates.

Models.py

```
class BasicModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.DateField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='sample')

class BasicModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = BasicModel
```

Views.py

```
def BasicView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BasicModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                    data = form.save()
                    return preview(request, data.id)
    else:
            form = BasicModelForm()
    return render_to_response("unnamed.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def preview(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BasicModel, pk=id)
    return render_to_response("preview.html", {'obj': obj})
```

preview.html

```
<html>
<body>
{{ obj.name.as_p }}
{{ obj.dob.as_p }}
{{ obj.photo.as_p }}
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me on this..I'm new to Django.

Thanks!

Comment: as_p is used for forms, not outputting object fields. Get rid and try again.

Comment: try `<img src='{{ obj.photo.url }}' title='{{ obj.name }}'/>`

Comment: @christophe31 I've done your syntax, it has no errors but the image is not displaying in the page. It's like unloaded image icon.

Answer (score 2):

You have to access to model properties. Model isn't form.

So:

```
<html>
<body>
{{ obj.name }}
{{ obj.dob }}
{{ obj.photo }}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ setting to get the image path. For data not display on template please check that data is committed and saved in database.